# Twitter error while posting message in android?

Tags: java, android, android-twitter

I am using twitter4j.jar for posting message in twitter.But while i am posting message in twitter my log-cat show below error.How i can solve this.Please can any one help me?

```
OAuth - Error sending to Twitter
410:
Relevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=15bb6564 or http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=010f3e5b
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[15bb6564-010f3e5b], statusCode=410, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.11}
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:199)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:75)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:112)
at twitter4j.Twitter.updateStatus(Twitter.java:593)
at com.android.abchealthgroup.facebook_twitter_post.TwitterUtils.sendTweet(TwitterUtils.java:40)
at com.android.abchealthgroup.facebook_twitter_post.PrepareRequestTokenActivity$RetrieveAccessTokenTask.executeAfterAccessTokenRetrieval(PrepareRequestTokenActivity.java:149)
at com.android.abchealthgroup.facebook_twitter_post.PrepareRequestTokenActivity$RetrieveAccessTokenTask.doInBackground(PrepareRequestTokenActivity.java:134)
at com.android.abchealthgroup.facebook_twitter_post.PrepareRequestTokenActivity$RetrieveAccessTokenTask.doInBackground(PrepareRequestTokenActivity.java:1)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which version of twitter4j do you use? The older ones will not work anymore since twitter dropped support for the old API yesterday.

Comment: I am using twitter4j-core-2.1.11.jar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

twitter4j-core-2.1.11 uses the Twitter API 1.0 which has been dropped by twitter yesterday (See announcements from twitter). To be able to use twitter in future you have to upgrade the twitter4j library to one which supports the newer twitter API 1.1. This is the case for the twitter4j 3.0.x releases.